# How to render newly uploaded images with rails and Ajax without reloading the whole page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

My rails image uploader uploads new cover photos to the home page via a modal form.  I'm trying to get Ajax working so new images will render/delete without the entire page reloading.

Here's what I have so far:

```
# app/views/covers/_new_cover.html.erb

<div class="modal-body">
  ....
  <%= form_for @cover, html: {multipart: :true}, remote: true do |f| %>
      <%= f.file_field :photo %>
  ....<%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
</div>
```

and:

```
# app/views/covers/new_cover.js.erb

$("#modal-window").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'covers/new_cover') %>");
```

The controller contains:

```
class CoversController < ApplicationController 
  def home
    @covers = Cover.all
    if logged_in?
      @micropost  = current_user.microposts.build
      @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end
  end

  def new
    @cover = Cover.new
  end

  def create
    @cover = Cover.new(cover_params)

    if @cover.save
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Cover photo uploaded."
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @cover = Cover.find(params[:id])
    @cover.destroy
    redirect_to root_path, notice:  "Cover photo deleted."
  end

  def new_cover
    @cover = Cover.new
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end

private
  def cover_params
    params.require(:cover).permit(:name, :photo)
  end
end
```

And routes.rb file contains:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'covers/new_cover' => 'covers#new_cover', :as => :new_cover
  get 'covers/home'
  get 'covers/new'
  get 'covers/create'
  get 'covers/destroy'

  root                'covers#home'

  resources :covers, only: [:home, :index, :new, :create, :destroy]
```

I've seen many similar issues on SO and via Google, but so far I'm unable to resolve it.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

i Hope after submitting the form it is going to `create` action, if so then create create.js.erb file in your views and load the div to which you are displaying `photo`

And change your create action to

```
def create
 @cover = Cover.new(cover_params)
    if @cover.save
     respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
     end
    else
      render "new"
    end
end
```

Comment: Hi @Prasanna, I shouldn't have omitted `<%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>` from my modal's code above.  I will edit my post.